# How can I convert real image to black and white image perfectly?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have used the Grey and Threshold tool of the Open CV library. However, it is not giving satisfying results. do any one knows any other method to convert the image into the b&w images. Check below, I have attached some of the bw images, that are so accurate.

[image]
[image]

Comment: We have no way to know what do you find wrong on those images

Comment: Please share your code and results; and explain why they are not satisfactory

Comment: When you say “b&w”, do you mean binary/bilevel, or do you mean grayscale? What is your input image? What is your expected result? Show what you tried!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that you tried `cv2.cvtColor(<ImagePath>, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`. This code changing it to GrayScale image. I tried it myself using your uploaded image and it's works. Here is the full code.

```py
import cv2
grayImage = cv2.imread('jeY9D.jpg')
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(grayImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('Testing', grayImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destoryAllWindows()
```

And here is the result.[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you want flexibility you can just make your own function that map a pixel on your img to black or white if it is below or above a given threshold

```py
def bin(img, threshold=128):
    bin_img= np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
    
    for i in range(img.shape[1]):
        for j in range(img.shape[0]):
            bin_img[j, i]= 0 if(img[j, i]<threshold) else 255

    return np.uint8(bin_img)
```

Here is an example if using 3 different threshold

```py
img_t_64= bin(img, 64)
img_t_128= bin(img)
img_t_192= bin(img, 192)


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 6))

ax = fig.add_subplot(131)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(132)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(133)

ax.set_title(f'threshold={64}')
ax2.set_title(f'threshold={128}')
ax3.set_title(f'threshold={192}')

ax.imshow(img_t_64, 'gray')
ax2.imshow(img_t_128, 'gray')
ax3.imshow(img_t_192, 'gray')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @CrisLuengo My bad, im not used to answering question and dont know that things like this are also noticed, Ill edit it